# Increase/decrease image size, website

Tags: image-scaling

i have a webpage with table and in it images,
i would like to add the option to increase/decrease image size, how could i do that?
Something like ctr+plus and ctr+ minus does.

This is what it is for now, http://www.ursic-ei.si/1.html

Thank you all for answers.

Comment: Do you want to actually change the image sizes in the original place, or simply display them at different sizes? Or are you simply asking how to present the options in the UI?

Comment: I would like to add two buttons so that user can increase or decrease image size (something like ctr+ plus and ctr+ minus). In default the image width is set like it is now: 900px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't increase image size - you display fixed size images.

Things you could do:

1. Have different sized copies of the same image and serve them selectively from the server when buttons pressed.
2. Serve a single larger image that will be auto scaled to fit dimensions of  element. Then alter the size of that element in JavaScript button event handlers.

   `document.getElementById("myImgElement").width = 300;`

   `document.getElementById("myImgElement").height= 300;`

You need to have an image larger than what you are down scaling to. The browser will scale it automatically to fit in the smaller image element. Note that you will need an image sufficiently big to fit your maximum size. Then downscale using code above.

Comment: I think the second option is what i would like to do, do you have any example links (like tutorial)?

Comment: @MB1 have in mind that this might increase the traffic between the server and the client if the images are big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to change the css of the image. Use width and height attributes to set them in css. Other option is to use jQuery plugin something like http://www.visual-blast.com/javascript/jqzoom-jquery-plugin/ or http://www.webappers.com/2008/12/16/jquery-javascript-image-magnifier-under-gpl/ This is triggered on mouseover but you can change the action to trigger the event.